# psensor stopped showing CPU temperature after AMD Ryzen upgrade

Tags: cpu, temperature, psensor

Recently I've upgraded my AMD Ryzen 5 2600 CPU to AMD Ryzen 5 5600x. psensor used to show the CPU temperature properly with the 2600, but after the upgrade, all I see is "temp1 0 degrees" ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9uq0.png)). Other temperatures (GPU, SSD etc.) shows properly. I've un/reinstalled psensor but it didn't work. Is there a fix to that?

PS: I've also updated my BIOS version during the CPU upgrade if it is related.

OS: Xubuntu 18.04 (Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-91-generic)

Motherboard: MSI X470 Gaming Plus